# No shadow with Eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadows

I have a problem creating an animated film as a university project. We work as a group. One of us created a landscape and the others animated a panda. I appended the landscape to the panda file and the others the panda into the landscape file. All my files have shadows on the ground from trees and the panda. The other files just have a shimmering shadow. I've been googling a lot but I can't find any solution. This happens only with Eevee, with Cycles all shadows are shown. I'll upload two files, one from me and one from a fellow student. Maybe someone can help me :)
[image: My file with shadow]
[image: Other file without shadow]

Best wishes
Nathalie

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(Not a complete answer, but comments have a limited amount of characters, and i still thought it helpful to share some things i noticed)

Wow, this is really weird. Most of your settings in EEVEE look the same but the color shading is different somehow. The sky (or himmel) object is light blue in the Shadow file, but the sky in the No Shadow file has a turquoise quality to it. I couldn't figure out why.

The most notable difference between the files was the scale, though. The sky object in the Shadow file is 430+ times larger than the the one in the No Shadow file ( I had to increase the Clip End value in the Shadow file a lot to be able to navigate the scene). This can account for a difference in resolution of shadows (one being sharp and another being very blurry and hardly noticeable) but I don't see how it would cause the absence of shadow.

I wonder how this scale difference happened and wonder about the way things where appended. Maybe it helps to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy element to the clipboard in one file and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste them in another in the future, instead of appending via file menu. In any case, the scale difference might point in the direction of solving the problem.

**EDIT:**

[In eevee, shadows are clipped by camera distance](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160067/in-eevee-shadows-are-clipped-by-camera-distance)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately we did not discuss about the size, so the landscape was much smaller than the panda. My fellow students scaled the panda smaller and I scaled the landscape bigger. This probably caused the problem. I will try to scale things up or down.

Comment: I got it! I set the Max Distance of the shadow from 1000 to 0.100 and there it is! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Ah, that makes sense : ) Glad I could help out a little. (For clarity I'll add a referral in my answer.) Good luck with you project.